# BLE: Where does the "handle" come from?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to learn how to use BLE on a Pi4.

I have installed hcitool and gatttool and have figured out how to use them. I have also set up a virtual device using LightBlue on a Mac.

```
pi@raspsky:~ $  sudo hcitool -i hci0 lescan
LE Scan ...
98:9E:63:39:8B:ED Blank
98:9E:63:39:8B:ED (unknown)
```

That "Blank" is the virtual device.

```
pi@raspsky:~ $ gatttool -b 98:9E:63:39:8B:ED -I
[98:9E:63:39:8B:ED][LE]> connect
Attempting to connect to 98:9E:63:39:8B:ED
Connection successful
[98:9E:63:39:8B:ED][LE]> primary
attr handle: 0x0001, end grp handle: 0x0005 uuid: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
<snip>
attr handle: 0x0028, end grp handle: 0x002b uuid: 00001111-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

```
[98:9E:63:39:8B:ED][LE]> char-desc
handle: 0x0001, uuid: 00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
<snip>
handle: 0x002b, uuid: 00002901-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

Now, I'd like to be able to read from the virtual device, but I have no idea which "handle" to use. I figured out by trial and error that I need to use 002b:

```
[98:9E:63:39:8B:ED][LE]> char-read-hnd 002b
Characteristic value/descriptor: 53 6f 6d 65 74 68 69 6e 67
```

That hex turns out to be the ascii string "Something" which is what I put in the virtual device.

But, where does that handle come from? It seems like I ought to be able to figure it out without having to use trial and error:

[image: Screenshot of LightBlue Virtual Device]

UPDATE:

In this example [Using bash and gatttool to get readings from Xiaomi Mijia LYWSD03MMC Temperature Humidity sensor](http://www.d0wn.com/using-bash-and-gatttool-to-get-readings-from-xiaomi-mijia-lywsd03mmc-temperature-humidity-sensor/), the author shows how to use hcitool to get the mac address of a BLE Device. The article then goes on with an example:

```
bt=$(timeout 15 gatttool -b A4:C1:38:8C:77:CA --char-write-req --handle='0x0038' --value="0100" --listen)
```

But the author never explains where the handle (handle='0x0038') came from. I see how you can get a list of handles using gatttool, but the only way I can figure out what data goes with each handle is to try each one until I find the one I want. There must be an easier way.

Comment: There is an explanation of where handles come from at: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781491900550/ch04.html. You can only find the value by doing service/characteristic discovery for that cached device. Typically the UUID is what is used at the key to find a characteristics value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you updated your question, I have another answer for you. But since your topic is not facing any programming issue, you better ask it again at another StackExchange.

> the only way I can figure out what data goes with each handle is to try each one **until I find the one I want**. There must be an easier way.

I guess I have to disappoint you here.

While there are some [predefined GATT profiles by Bluetooth SIG](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/), most of the proprietary implementations do not expose any meaningful information about their characteristics but the mandatory UUIDs.

If you are lucky, you might be able to find a **Characteristic User Description** (Bluetooth Core Spec Vol. 3 Part G 3.3.3.2) or deduce some information from a **Characteristic Presentation Format** (Bluetooth Core Spec Vol. 3 Part G  3.3.3.5) characteristic descriptor; but since these are optional, I doubt that a proprietary implementation will provide these.

So for a proprietary implementation, you have to reverse engineer that information or try to find it online (often other people already reversed engineered common devices).

Answer (score 2):

hcitool, and gatttool were [deprecated by the BlueZ project](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) in 2017. If you are following a tutorial that uses them, there is a chance that it might be out of date. The current BlueZ tool for generic scanning and exploration is `bluetoothctl`.

With BLE the UUID is the key to identifying the service/characteristic/descriptor that you are interested in.

The [16-bit UUID Numbers Document](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/) lists the adopted UUIDs. SIG-adopted attribute types (UUIDs) share all but 16 bits of a special 128-bit base UUID:`0000xxxx-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB`. The document lists the 16-bit value that goes into that base.

As you have with the virtual device using LightBlue, [custom UUIDs](https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-gatt-services-characteristics/) can be created. These need to be outside of the 128-bit base reserved for SIG-adopted values.

As SO is about software development, I'll point you at the [BlueZ API documentation](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc) should you want to do any of this with code. There are also [examples](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test) in the BlueZ source tree.

Comment: I now realize that I posted this question in the wrong place. I will post it again elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are looking for is generally speaking GATT/ATT itself.

Basically you query a device implementing a GATT server

The best (res)source and reference for anything related to Bluetooth® is IMHO the [Bluetooth Core Specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification/) in the version your devices support and you are developing for.

### Attribute Protocol (ATT)

**Bluetooth Core Specification 5.2 Vol. 3 Part F** describes the *ATTRIBUTE PROTOCOL (ATT)* as follows:

> This Part defines the Attribute protocol; a protocol for discovering, reading, and writing attributes on a peer device

The ATT is some sort of "low level" since it describe the actual protocol itself and its messages / Protocol Data Units (PDUs), but it's definitely  worth a (periphere) read, especial chapters *3.1 Introduction* and *3.2 Basic Concepts*.

### Generic Attribute Profile (GATT)

**Bluetooth Core Specification 5.2 Vol. 3 Part G** describes the *GENERIC ATTRIBUTE PROFILE (GATT)* as follows:

> This Part defines the Generic Attribute Profile that describes a service framework using the Attribute protocol for discovering services, and for reading and writing characteristic values on a peer device.

You can think of GATT like a high-level API for issuing ATT queries and commands.

You should definitely give the complete chapter *2.6 GATT Profile Hierarchy* a read and then head over to *4 GATT Feature Requirements*, especially chapters *4.4 Primary Service Discovery*, *4.6 Charateristic discovery* and *4.7 Characteristic Descriptor Discovery - regarding your question

> But, where does that handle come from?

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't state my question clearly enough. I've updated the question with a clarification.